# While using "flutter run" in VS Code terminal, The terminal changing automatically to current working directory

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

In my project, I have created a sub-directory to maintain it. But while using "flutter run" from the directory where my main.dart file is, the terminal automatically changes to the current working directory, and shows

> Target file "lib\main.dart" not found.

How do I resolve it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run using a specific target file with the `-t` parameter :

`flutter run -t example/main.dart`